# Is there a way to create unique bins for each row of data?

Tags: r, dplyr, binning

I have a data set with the minimum and maximum heights for multiple objects. The data frame looks like such:

```
ID Min Max  
A  30  160  
B  12  200  
C  35  171  
D  16  198
```

I want to split the distance between the Min and Max, to create 3 bins "Bottom", "Middle", and "Top". I want the bins to represent 1/3 of the range between Min and Max. This is my expected output (decimals are okay, I am just rounding here):

```
ID Bottom Middle Top   
A  30-73  74-116 117-160  
B  12-75  76-137 138-200  
C  35-80  81-125 126-171  
D  16-77  78-138 139-198
```

Is there a way to do this in dplyr?

Additionally, I will be using the ranges created from these bins to compare to another, separate, data set tracking particle motion for each unique ID within these ranges. I want to know how often each particle was in "Bottom", "Middle", or "Top". Is there a way to do this with separate files, or should I combine them somehow?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I added the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringr)

    dataset <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                          Min = c(30, 12, 35, 16),
                          Max = c(160, 200, 171, 198))

    datasetBins <- dataset %>%
# Getting bins limits (using floor() to make them separable)
      mutate(quater = (Max - Min) / 3) %>%
      mutate(limit2 = floor(Min + quater),
             limit3 = floor(Min + 2* quater)) %>%
# Creating bins (using +1 to make them separable)
      mutate(Bottom = str_c(Min, limit2, sep = "-"),
             Middle = str_c(limit2+1, limit3, sep = "-"),
             Top = str_c(limit3+1, Max, sep = "-")) %>%
# Droping redundant cols
      select(ID, Bottom, Middle, Top)
```

Alternatively, if you want this data frame to be useful when comparing with numerical values, I would stop at limits computation. Then you can use `ifelse()` to check consecutives limits, to place given value in proper bin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution by defining custom function `f`

```
f <- Vectorize(function(l,u) {
  ur <- round((u-l)/3*(1:3)+l)
  lr <- c(l,ur[1:2]+1)
  paste(lr,ur,sep = "-")
})

dfout <- cbind(df[1],
               `colnames<-`(t(f(df$Min,df$Max)),c("Bottom","Middle","Top")))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  ID Bottom Middle     Top
1  A  30-73 74-117 118-160
2  B  12-75 76-137 138-200
3  C  35-80 81-126 127-171
4  D  16-77 78-137 138-198
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), Min = c(30, 12, 35, 16), Max = c(160, 
200, 171, 198)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```